# Create a function that converts decimals into IEEE 754 floating point precision numbers using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, binary, floating-point, converters, ieee-754

I need to create a function that does exactly as the title says and outputs a 32 character string. So far I can get the signed bit and the exponential part correctly. What I'm struggling with is calculating the fractional 23 bit portion. The assignment I'm working on also has you use a code skeleton which is strange.

```
function [out] = IEEE754Converter(N)

if N==0
    s= 0;
    e=0;
    f=0;
    out= '00000000000000000000000000000000';

else
% assign sign value
if N<0
    s = '1';
else
    s = '0';
end

% take absolute value of N since we know sign already
N = abs(N);

% get exponent (unbiased and in decimal)
e_temp = floor(log2(N));

% turn e to binary
e = dec2bin(127+e_temp);

% get fraction (in decimal, lose the 1)
f_temp = N-floor(N);

% start f as empty
f = [];

% loop through decimal places
for i = 1:23
    if f_temp>2^-i   % check if fraction is big enough to have non-zero place holder
            % for 2^-i, then this place holder has a 1.
            f = [f,'1'];

            % remove placed decimal value from f_temp for future
            % iterations.
            f_temp = f_temp-1;

    else
            % in this case, this binary placeholder is 0
            f = [f,'0'];
    end
end
out= [s e f]; %Do Not change the lines after this
if (N~=0)
find (out=='1')
end

end % end IEEE75Converter
end
```

Comment: Are you trying to reimplement `sprintf('%u32',java.lang.Float.floatToRawIntBits(N))`?

Comment: You could a java method... as Daniel said whilst I was typing that

Comment: @Daniel Yes basically